# How to handle sensitive information in questions?

Tags: discussion

When a user posts/edits a question, and unknowingly posts sensitive information like username/password to a database. How should this be handled?

I came across one, but now it's in the revision history. Can/should a moderator handle this? I've flagged with moderator's attention, or is there a better way?

Comment: It's always in the revision history.  Even if there were a way to remove it, the user should immediately change the password and what not.  Others may have copied it before it was removed from the post.  I've even noticed Google pick up on these things within seconds of the post.

Comment: Meta SE post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132117/what-should-i-do-if-a-user-posts-sensitive-information-as-part-of-a-question-or

Comment: Aha thanks, I was searching on the wrong meta. :)

Comment: The last time I noticed something that looked like sensitive info (an API key), I mentioned it in a comment and the OP said that it was for a test account he created specifically so we could try it, not the production key.

Comment: I have done this, but the username/password is always for a debug server that can’t be reached from the internet, so it is often not the problem it looks like at first sight.